# SOLR 9 - Delete Schema from Schema Designer

Tags: solr, solr9

I am trying to delete a schema from SOLR 9. The schemas were created as part of following the tutorials: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/getting-started/tutorial-films.html

The schema designer doesn't seem to have an option to delete:
https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/schema-designer.html

I have tried deleting the core by executing the command:

```
C:\solr-9.0.0>bin\solr.cmd delete -c <core name>
```

but the schema still stays.

Can anyone advise how to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Thought to answer this question lately while I was looking for the answers as well. After a few searches I figured out below steps to remove the config(s):

- Install Elkozmon ZooNavigator (https://zoonavigator.elkozmon.com/en/latest/ Web UI for ZooKeeper): Since, I have my Zookeeper running locally outside docker container, I had to start the ZooNavigator disabling the network mode.

```
docker run \
  -d -p 9000:9000 \
  --name zoonavigator \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  elkozmon/zoonavigator:latest
```

- Access ZooNavigator at http://localhost:9000/connect and provide:

  - Connection String: `host.docker.internal:2181`. Since, I have my setup on WindowsOS with Docker v18.03+, I used the special DNS name `host.docker.internal` which will resolve to the internal IP address used by the host.
  - Leave "Auth Username" & "Auth Password" empty and click connect.
  - On the left side navigation window, navigate into `solr/configs` location and you will see all the configs available including the ones created through Solr schema designer console. Click on the 3 vertical dots against the config for an option to delete the config. Delete the ones you are looking for and you are done!

Hope this helps!